# Detect endianness with type punning & padding bits

Tags: c, padding, endianness

Here is a common trick used to detect endianness at runtime, seen for instance in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/misc/endiantest.html):

```
int x = 1;

if (*(char *)&x == 1)
{
  /* little-endian */
}
else
{
  /* big-endian */
}
```

According to my reading of the standard, it does not lead to an undefined behavior since it does not break the strict aliasing rule.

Anyway, as long as an integer type other than `unsigned char` can contain padding bits (such as `x`), couldn't the condition `*(char *)x == 1` be wrong even if it is a little-endian system?

In that case, is the solution with unions better for doing this?

Comment: What is the meaning of "endianness" on systems that can intersperse arbitrary padding into integral variables? All that the reinterpret-as-char shows you is the binary representation of your data. It's up to **you** to assign a cute name to it.

Comment: The main problem with this code is that it assumes the system is either little or big endian.  If its neither, it will miscategorize it as one or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure endianness really makes sense when you have padding bits, but the otherwise you are right and the condition might be wrong. At least you are not invoking undefined behavior as character types have no trap representations.

Otherwise what you can do is to use exact-width integer types (like `uint32_t`, etc.). Although these types are optional, they are guaranteed to have no padding bits.

For information, note that `signed char` also cannot have padding bits.

Comment: Character types not having trap representations is not the reason why `*(char *)&x` is defined. In an implementation on which neither 32-bit `int` nor 32-bit `float` have padding bits, `*(int *)&f` is still undefined. The reason why `*(char *)&x` is not undefined is that the list in C99's clause 6.5:7 ends in “a character type”. This clause is known as the “strict aliasing” clause, and it's for real, as a google or StackOverflow search should show.

Comment: @PascalCuoq *Character types not having trap representations is not the reason...* But I never meant it was the reason. I didn't evoke aliasing because OP already correctly said there is no aliasing violations with his example. I mentioned there is no trap to explicit that even if there are unspecified padding bits, the reading of these bits cannot invoke undefined behavior as they cannot be a trap representation.